# How to call parent function from callback function in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-components

Here is a class

```
export class ChatDetailPage {

constructor(){

}

funcA(){
     var options = {
        onSubmit: function (text) {
        //i want to be able to access funcB from here 
        this.funcB(text)
          },
this.nativeKeyboard.showMessenger(options)
}

funcB(text){
  alert (text);
}

}
```

Here in this case how can i call funcB from onsubmit callback function in Anular 2 or Ionic 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an arrow function, which captures the value of `this`:

```
export class ChatDetailPage {

    constructor(){

    }

    funcA(){
       var options = {
           onSubmit: text => {
              //i want to be able to access funcB from here 
              this.funcB(text)
           },
       };
       this.nativeKeyboard.showMessenger(options)
   }

   funcB(text){
      alert (text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you won't be able to use an arrow function, f.e. when it's an inbuilt or library function. The solution you can use in this case is bind the `this` variable to a variable called `self` or whatever you want.

```
funcA(){
     // bind the this variable to 'self' outside of the function scope
     var self = this;
     var options = {
        onSubmit: function (text) {
            // and use self instead of this 
            self.funcB(text)
        },
     this.nativeKeyboard.showMessenger(options)
}

funcB(text){
  alert (text);
}
```